# Drupal: how to set role permissions for specific content types and views?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

how can I set role permissions (content access) for specific content types, rather than CCK fields ?

I actually want the login page to appear of the user access to pages of a specific content type, or a specific view

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem
http://drupal.org/project/content_access
http://drupal.org/project/node_privacy_byrole
Then in the site configuration change the access denied page to "user/login". This should do the job.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I still have a small question: do you know how can I output a line of text in the empty page ? I can easily do this with a View, but not for the single nodes, or taxonomy lists of nodes.

Comment: You mean, how can you customize the 403 error page? You might try something like the custom404 module.

Comment: nono.. For example, if an user visit a view with only nodes he is not authorized to see, the view is empty. (not error message). In this case I can specify the "empty view" message from the view settings(and so I've done). However, if the user visit a taxonomy term page, the page is empty (no error page, just blank page) but I don't have any option to set an "empty page" custom message.

Comment: In views you can write in php code into the header. The code in the header is executed before the view is rendered I guess. You can use the header for validating if the user is logged in or belongs to a specific role and then direct him to where ever you want. Here I am referring to the view header and not the common page header.